# Can SignalR be used to send a message from a console application that will show in a browser?

Tags: javascript, windows, signalr

I need a server process (running on windows server) to send short messages to a particular user that has a SharePoint served page open in the browser. 
I can embed JavaScript in the page to intercept the message and use a toast to show it.
Can someone point me to examples to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You would do it similar to a signalr self hosted console app. You can find a tutorial here:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: Thanks I will try this